# Sorting EAV database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to stort a EAV table and I can't get it to work.
I get the result but I can't get it to sort.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    formFields.uid,
    formFields.formId,
    formFields.postId,
    formFields.name,
    formFields.value
FROM formFields
INNER JOIN formFields aux
    ON (aux.name = "date")
WHERE
    formFields.formId = "1789"
    AND formFields.deleted = 0
    AND formFields.hidden = 0
ORDER BY aux.value DESC
```

This is the table:

```
uid formId  postId  name    value
1   1789    1   title   example title #1
2   1789    1   date    1341091600
3   1789    2   title   example title #2
4   1789    2   date    1341092300
5   1789    3   title   example title #3
6   1789    3   date    1341081200
```

And this is the result I need:

```
uid formId  postId  name    value
3   1789    2   title   example title #2
4   1789    2   date    1341092300
1   1789    1   title   example title #1
2   1789    1   date    1341091600
5   1789    3   title   example title #3
6   1789    3   date    1341081200
```

The result is sorted by the value that has date in the name column
(the values are just examples)

Edit: here is a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d3c32/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `ORDER BY` the `date` value then you can use something like this:

```
SELECT
  formFields.uid,
  formFields.formId,
  formFields.postId,
  formFields.name,
  formFields.value 
  FROM formFields
INNER JOIN formFields aux 
  ON (aux.name = "date")
WHERE formFields.formId = "1789"
  AND formFields.deleted = 0
  AND formFields.hidden = 0
ORDER BY case when formFields.name = 'date' then 0 else 1 end
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d3c32/9)

Comment: Doesn't work either the posts that are saved in this table are still printed in the same order. Here is what the original query without sorting looks like. And this works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b70/2

Comment: There must be another error since it should not have to return more than 12 rows

Comment: @Patrik I started with your original fiddle you posted on the other answer.  It had more than 12 rows.   Let me check the order by as well

Comment: @Patrik what exactly are you trying to do with this query?  Since your sample query is joining on the same table twice that is why you are getting more rows then you should.

Comment: Yes that was an error I made when I wrote the query. (I have updated that query now).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to sort by a value that depends on another column. I want to sort by the column value if where the column name is equal to date

Comment: The rows are connected to each other by postId. This is each post.

Comment: No it doesn't :/ Here is the result array after running the query: http://pastebin.com/GB5kbKhy (just after a while loop) and here is after adding some files to the result http://pastebin.com/px8XPUjX (this is what's sent to the function that just foreach it)

Comment: how can I sort this ASC/DESC?

Comment: @Patrik You can place `DESC` after the `END` statement, see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d3c32/30)

Comment: This must be right. Probably my other code that is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even this question is superb old question. I want to keep the accurate answer here on how to perform data sorting on EAV.

To achieve the expectation in the original question, the following SQL can be used to sort the specified column.

```
SELECT mdata.uid, mdata.formId, mdata.postId, mdata.name, mdata.value
FROM formFields mdata
WHERE mdata.formId = '1789'
    AND mdata.deleted = 0
    AND mdata.hidden = 0
ORDER BY (
    SELECT s.value FROM formFields s 
    WHERE s.name='date' 
    AND s.postId=mdata.postId
) DESC
```

The above SQL will produce the following result.

```
uid formId  postId  name    value
3   1789    2   title   example title #2
4   1789    2   date    1341092300
1   1789    1   title   example title #1
2   1789    1   date    1341091600
5   1789    3   title   example title #3
6   1789    3   date    1341081200
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: A beautiful, simple and concise answer using ORDER BY with a SELECT subquery. I have a rather large EAV query which contains no JOINs and I wasn't keen to add any.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT     formFields.uid,     
      formFields.formId,     
      formFields.postId, 
      formFields.name,
     formFields.value 
 FROM formFields tx_gcgluteusfeed_formFields 
 INNER JOIN formFields b  
      ON formFields.postId = b.postId 
 INNER JOIN formFields c 
      ON (c.name = "date")  
 WHERE  ormFields.formId = "1789" 
      AND formFields.deleted = 0 
      AND formFields.hidden = 0 
 ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

if you want order by first column

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. It may be the rest of the query that is wrong. I made a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d3c32/2